# Solve the equation: $\sin 3x=2\cos^3x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation  :

$$\sin 3x=2\cos^3x$$

my try :

$\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x$

$\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$

so:

$$3\sin x-4\sin^3x=2((1-\sin^2x)(\cos x))$$

then ?

Comment: You have too many `2`s on the right hand side.

Comment: And I don't think the left hand side is very helpful. I would look for ways to reduce everything in terms of $sin x$ and $cos x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$2\cos^3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x$$

Divide both sides by $\cos^3x$

$$2=3\tan x(1+\tan^2x)-4\tan^3x$$

$$\tan^3x-3\tan x+2=0$$ which is a cubic equation in $\tan x$

Clearly, one of the roots is $\tan x=1$

Comment: Oh, even better, a quadratic in tan!  :D

Answer (score 6):

#### Hint:

$$\sin 3x=2\cos^3x$$
$$3\sin x-4\sin^3x=2\cos^3x$$
$$3\sin x(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)-4\sin^3x=2\cos^3x$$
$$\sin^3x-3\sin x\cos^2x+2\cos^3x=0$$
Divide both sides by $\cos^3x$ and $\tan x=t$
$$t^3-3t+2=0$$
$$(t-1)^2(t+2)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

1st of all you need to learn the formula Sin 3x and remember it so that whenever you see such a question you will choose the right way.
1st learn it . This may help you to learn this
https://youtu.be/He4JXYBwTj4

Come to our answer

sin 3x = 2 cos³ x

3sinx-4sin³x=2cos³x

(here look at the expression should you expand it in terms of cubic terms, obviously no it will mess up as in your case, it will be like doing so much thing for getting a small result. So here we will rather than expanding it we will divide cos³x on rhs. )

3tanxsec²x-4tan³x=2

Let tan x = t

So,

3 t (1+t²)-4t³=2
Then solve it and get

Tan x = 1 and -2

Hope it helps.